# Lightning Aura Component Action failed: c:param$controller$doInit [acction is not defined] Failing descriptor: {c:param$controller$doInit}

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

I am creating a lightning component and the init function is declared in the controller js file.

But I am getting an error stating that "doInit action is not defined".

Here goes the code:

Component file:

```
<aura:component controller="AccountListSearchController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"> <!--access="global"-->     
<aura:attribute name="lstAccount" type="Account[]"/>     
<aura:attribute name="columnsToDisplay" type="List"/>     <aura:attribute name="searchKeyword" type="String"/>     <aura:attribute name="newMessage" type="String" default="Hello there!"/>          <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>          <h2>{!v.newmessage}</h2>          <lightning:card iconName="standard:account" title="Account List">              <lightning:layout>         <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">             <lightning:input aura:id="searchField"                                  label="Account Name/Email/Phone"                                  value="{!v.searchKeyword}"                                   placeholder="Search Accouts"                                  onchange="searchAccounts"/>             </lightning:layoutItem>         </lightning:layout>                  <lightning:datatable data="{!v.lstAccount}"                              columns="{!v.columnsToDisplay}"                              keyField="Id"                              hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>              </lightning:card> </aura:component>
```

JS Controller File:

```
({  doInit : function(component, event, helper) {  helper.fetchAccHelper(null, component);   },          searchAccounts: function(component, event, helper) {         var searchValue = component.find("searchField").get("v.value");         helper.fetchAccHelper(searchValue, component);     } })
```

JS Helper File:

```
({  fetchAccHelper : function(searchVal, component) {  component.set("v.columnsToDisplay", [             {label: "Account Name", fieldName: "Name", type: "text"},             {label: "Account Number", fieldName: "AccountNumber", type: "text"},             {label: "Account Owner", fieldName: "OwnerId", type: "text"},             {label: "Phone", fieldName: "Phone", type: "text"}         ]);                  var action = component.get("c.fetchAccount");         acction.setParams({             "searchKeyWord": searchVal         });                  action.setCallback(this, function(response){             var state = response.getState();             if(state == "SUCCESS"){                 component.set("v.lstAccount", response.getReturnValue());             }             else{                 alert("An error occured while fetching the data");             }         });         $A.enqueueAction(action);  } })
```

Apex Controller file:

```
public class AccountListSearchController {  @AuraEnabled     public static List<Account> fetchAccount(String searchKeyWord){         List<Account> returnList = new List<Account>();         String searchKey = String.isBlank(searchKeyWord) ? '%%' : '%' + searchKeyWord + '%';                  returnList = [SELECT Name,AccountNumber,OwnerId,Phone FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :searchKey OR Phone LIKE :searchKey];                   return returnList;     } }
```

Application file:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">     <c:AccountListSearch newMessage="This is a new mmessage"/> </aura:application>
```

When the app file is previewed the following error occurs:

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed: c:AccountListSearch$controller$doInit [acction is not defined] Failing descriptor: {c:AccountListSearch$controller$doInit}

Please help. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnTXV.jpg)

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I am getting an error stating that "doInit action is not defined".

No, you're getting "acction is not defined". With double C.

```
var action = component.get("c.fetchAccount");
acction.setParams({                           // typo
    "searchKeyWord": searchVal
});
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
```

It's pretty easy when you see it like that, there's no such variable "acction".

You have more typos there. JavaScript is case-sensitive so you need to make up your mind whether the text variable is "newMessage" or "newmessage" too, you'll get access errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I absolutely missed the typo.

Comment: If you work in Developer Console - consider switching over to VSCode + sfdx + eslint plugin, it should nicely underline such "grammar error" like MS Word / Outlook. It's bit more work to install everything but pays off when you make trickier components. sfdx has similar scanner plugin: https://forcedotcom.github.io/sfdx-scanner/

Comment: I have just configured the VS Code and am planning to switch from dev console.

Comment: Meanwhile I have been building up on the previous code and again stuck on an undefined variable.  Added this part in the component file : <lightning:datatable data="{!v.lstAccount}"
                             columns="{!v.columnsToDisplay}"
                             keyField="Id"
                             hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                             onrowaction="{!c.editRecord}"/> and the following functions in the js controller and helper respectively. editRecord : function(component, event, helper){
     helper.editRecordHelper(component, event);
    },

Comment: editRecordHelper : function(component, event){
     var recId = event.getParam('row').Id;
        var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
        editRecordEvent.setParams({
                "recordId": recId
       });
        editRecordEvent.fire();
 } I am getting the following error: Action failed: c:AccountListSearch$controller$editRecord [editRecordEvent is undefined]
Failing descriptor: {c:AccountListSearch$controller$editRecord}. Can you please help.

Comment: use Setup -> Debug mode to make the final code closer to what you type (by default SF optimizes it for production, not debug). Put some "debugger;" statements in your code or breakpoints in browser's JS console (Ctrl+Shift+J, F12 etc, NOT the SF developer console). Try to step through function calls, even 1 line at a time to figure out where it errors. I can't read it like that from comments, post new question or update this one if you're still stuck

Comment: Hello Tomasz, I had it figured out. Thanks for your help and insight.